# DADiskEject causing problems with error code 12 (kDAReturnUnsupported)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, diskarbitration

I try to eject external USB drives and Disk Images after being unmounted in the following callback function:

```
void __unmountCallback(DADiskRef disk, DADissenterRef dissenter, void *context )
{
    ...
    if (!dissenter) 
    {
        DADiskEject(disk, 
                    kDADiskEjectOptionDefault, 
                    __ejectCallback, 
                    NULL);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error in __ejectCallback...

```
void __ejectCallback(DADiskRef disk, DADissenterRef dissenter, void * context)
{
    if(dissenter) 
    {
       DAReturn status = DADissenterGetStatus(dissenter);
       if(unix_err(status)) 
       {
        int code = err_get_code(status);
            ...
       }
    }
}
```

The error code is 12 meaning kDAReturnUnsupported. I don't really know what is going wrong. Can anyone please comment on this? Does this mean disk images can not be ejected???
Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is pretty unclear on this. Therefore, it's a good idea to look into the actual [source code of the DARequest class](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration-129/diskarbitrationd/DARequest.c) to find out what causes the `kDAReturnUnsupported` response.

It reveals the following conditions that return a `kDAReturnUnsupported` response:

**Does your DADisk instance represent the entire volume or not?**

```
if ( DADiskGetDescription(disk, kDADiskDescriptionMediaWholeKey) == NULL )
{
    status = kDAReturnUnsupported;
}

if ( DADiskGetDescription(disk, kDADiskDescriptionMediaWholeKey) == kCFBooleanFalse )
{
     status = kDAReturnUnsupported;
}
```

Looking into the IO Kit documentation (for which DiscArbitation.framework is a wrapper for), we find that `kDADiskDescriptionMediaWholeKey` describes whether the media is whole or not (that is, it represents the whole disk or a partition on it), so check that you're ejecting the entire disc and not a partition. Remember, you can unmount a partition, but you can't eject it. (that wouldn't make sense)

**Is the disc mountable?**

Another condition in `DARequest.c` is whether the volume is mountable or not, so make sure it is:

```
if (DADiskGetDescription(disk, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeMountableKey) == kCFBooleanFalse )
{
     status = kDAReturnUnsupported;
}
```

**Is the DADisk instance's name valid?**

A third check validates the volume's name. Some system provided (internal) volumes don't have a name and can't be ejected. The check is very simple and simply looks for *any* name, so this shouldn't be a big deal.

```
if (DARequestGetArgument2(request) == NULL)
{
    status = kDAReturnUnsupported;
}
```

Go through these three checks and see if they apply to you. This way you're bound to find out what's wrong.